# Extract values of whiskers from boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

Considering boxplot of `rivers` as below:

`boxplot(rivers, col='chartreuse3', ylab='length of rivers')`

My questions are:

1. What is skewness of this distribution
2. How can I extract values of whiskers in above plot.
3. What are the exact outliers values?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`boxplot` both plots the boxplot and returns the values that comprise it:

```
> y <- boxplot(rivers, col='chartreuse3', ylab='length of rivers')
> y$stats
     [,1]
[1,]  135
[2,]  310
[3,]  425
[4,]  680
[5,] 1205
> y$out
 [1] 1459 1450 1243 2348 3710 2315 2533 1306 1270 1885 1770
```